# Taking tax paid money back home to India from Singapore

Tags: india, money-transfer, international-transfer, singapore

I have worked in singapore , 30 months and paid all my taxes. I hold an NRO account in India. I do not have any NRE account. I need to transfer my post tax paid saving to India bank as I return home. Can I bring a bankers cheque or DD from singapore bank . I do not have time for NRE account 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Can I bring a bankers cheque or DD from singapore bank .

Yes you can.  Remember if they are payable in Singapore, i.e. SGD denominated, they will take time to clear; typically around a month.

Alternatively you can approach an Indian Bank in Singapore they can arrange for a Rupee draft payable in city of your choice. The Banks also have a facility of opening an NRE account in the city/Branch of your choice by opening account with wire transfer.

> I do not have time for NRE account

Money can be transferred into your NRO account as well.

You could also use remittance services that provide better exchange rates.